# Executing Asterisk speech recognition application using AsterNET.ARI

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari, asternet

I have a sample dialplan:

```
exten => 1,1,Wait(1)
exten => 1,n,SpeechCreate
exten => 1,n,SpeechBackground(beep)
exten => 1,n,Verbose(0, ${SPEECH_TEXT(0)})
exten => 1,n,Hangup()
```

And I need to execute speech recognition using ARI stasis application and get recognition result in this application using AsterNET.ARI library.

Currently everything is configured and stasis application connects and receives events:

```
static async void c_OnStasisStartEvent(IAriClient sender, StasisStartEvent e)
{
    // Answer the channel
    await sender.Channels.AnswerAsync(e.Channel.Id);

    // Play an announcement
    await sender.Channels.PlayAsync(e.Channel.Id, "sound:hello-world");
}
```

But I don't know how to call an extension application. For example this dialplan string: `exten => 1,n,SpeechBackground(beep)`

I tried something like this:

```
var endpoints = sender.Endpoints.List();
await sender.Channels.OriginateAsync(endpoints[0].Resource, "1,n,BackGround(hello-world)");
```

But it results in exception: `Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).`

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To make the RTP audio streams ready for use ( open it ) i recommended not to use...

```
exten => 1,1,Wait(1)
```

...try...

```
exten => 1,1,Answer(1000)
```

...instead.

Read: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Answer%2C+Playback%2C+and+Hangup+Applications

Comment: I have no issues with the dialplan itself. The question is about executing extension application from AsterNET.ARI stasis application.